# The purpose of the post_date_gmt?

Tags: date

Why do we have 2 date fields in the `wp_posts`? What's the purpose of the `post_date_gmt`? When does storing the Greenwich time get handy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some countries use a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time):

> Typically clocks are adjusted forward one hour near the start of spring and are adjusted backward in autumn.

Sometimes there is no 2 am. Sometimes you get 2 am two times. To avoid cron jobs running twice or not at all WP needs the GMT (or more precise: [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)). UNIX time stamps cannot be used because they start in 1970 … and there is still the [Year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

If you want to write an imaginary diary of Gaius Julius Caesar or James T. Kirk … you will run into problems with the current system too, but they *may be* solvable at least. :)